# Vue js for each uninterrupted set of recieved messages place an icon at the last element

Tags: arrays, vue.js, for-loop, foreach, chat

I got this cosmetic problem where there is this v-for loop for message fetching and i want every last message of recieved message streak to bear an icon of the user you're chatting with. Just like in picture related.

[image: notice the icon at the uninterruped end of recieved messages]

Now... I know how to style it... But the v-for loop is preventing me from from using something like this...

```html
<div class="messagegroup recieved">
  <div class="iconcontainer">
    <div class="iconcontainerinner">
      <img class='usericoncontacts' src="../assets/icons8-male-user-100.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="textmessages recieved">
    <div class="message">
      <span>Hello</span>
    </div>
    <div class="message">
      <span>How are you?</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

which looks something like this

[image]

but instead, because I'm unable to somehow group recieved text messages i must go on with code that goes something like this...

```html
<div v-if='selectedContact' class="textmessages">
  <div
    v-for="message in messages" 
    v-if="message.messageTo == selectedContact.userid || message.messageFrom == selectedContact.userid"  
    :key="message.messageFrom" 
    :class="[message.messageFrom==authUser.uid?'message':'message recieved']"
  >
    <span>{{ message.message }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

which unfortunately only gives this basic chat structure that looks something like this...
[image]

The messages array is an array of objects which have data in them like this...

```
author: "Matěj Pospíšil"
createdAt: July 13, 2020 at 2:43:17 PM UTC+2
message: "Hello"
messageFrom: "exl21qLb1yW3qNUFgpcZv3BRnyI2"
messageTo: "xTw8bWpVTwaj05TBTudBNLV2XEE3"
```

Please if you somehow understand my broken english be so kind and teach me. I bet this thing is trivial, but I just couldn't find any answers on web so please be so kind...
Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you please show an example of the `messages` array? The one from your last screenshot would be ideal

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62886202/edit) with that data.

Comment: done and done, Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking some big guesses about the structure of your data but what I would do is create a computed property that does two things...

1. Filters the list of messages to just ones from or to the selected user
2. Chunk the messages into groups of sent and received

```js
computed: {
  conversation () {
    if (!this.selectedContact) {
      return []
    }
    // filter for the selected user
    const messages = this.messages.filter(({ messageTo, messageFrom }) =>
      messageTo === selectedContact.userid || messageFrom === selectedContact.userid)

    // create a new array chunked by sender
    return messages.reduce((chunks, { messageFrom, message }) => {
      let last = chunks[chunks.length - 1]
      if (last?.uid !== messageFrom) {
        chunks.push(last = {
          uid: messageFrom, 
          messages: [],
          received: messageFrom !== this.authUser.uid // a handy flag for CSS classes
        })
      }
      last.messages.push(message)
      return chunks
    }, [])
  }
}
```

Now you can use this to drive your template

```html
<div
  v-for="messageGroup in conversation" 
  class="messagegroup" 
  :class="{ received: messageGroup.received }"
>
  <div v-if="messageGroup.received" class="iconcontainer">
    <div class="iconcontainerinner">
      <img class='usericoncontacts' src="../assets/icons8-male-user-100.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="textmessages" :class="{ received: messageGroup.received }">
    <div class="message" v-for="message in messageGroup.messages">
      <span>{{ message }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, 1 detail I missed. I already filtered all messages that have something to do with this.authUser.uid wheather it is messageFrom or messageTo. In short I'm only fetching messages that have something to do with current user logged in so I don't have to fetch ALL messages from the database.

Comment: The filter part in my answer is about showing the messages to or from the `selectedContact`. In your question you're using a `v-if` but Vue throws warnings about that and you should use a computed

Comment: the only error you got is that you didn't apply this.selectedContact to computed method. Otherwise it works quite well thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It's right there in the filter